# Xcode: how to install the iOS documentation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I currently have Xcode 3.2.3 installed (sans iOS SDK). It seems to have automatically downloaded for me the (OSX) Cocoa dev library -- but not iOS (UIKit) documentation.

In Xcode preferences, I see "documentation set" options for "Mac OSX 10.6 Core Library" and "Xcode 3.2 Developer Tools Library" (both already downloaded) -- plus some Java etc. documentation. But nothing about iPhone/iOS/UIKit.

After actually installing the iOS SDK, will there be a new option for an iOS documentation set in Xcode preferences? Or do I have to do something manually?

Comment: My installation seemed to be automatic, i.e. the iOS4 docs were installed with Xcode 3.2.3.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I've got the iOS SDK installed, it does have iOS documentation listed in the Xcode Prefs document lists. In fact a surfeit of them: "iPhone OS 4.0 Library" (downloads automatically), "iOS 4.0 Library" (GET button), "Apple iPhone OS" (seeming stray entry with no GET or info buttons).

Answer (score 5):

The Documentation for iOS is no longer a part of SDK - looks like you need to install from preferences of XCode - click get next to install it

Answer (score 3):

Click on preferences
Click on the 'Documentation
'Get' the iOS documentation

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is part of the SDK. Once you install the iOS SDK you should then see the documentation show up (and unfortunately take priority in searches showing up first even when you only have Mac OS projects open).

Comment: There is little love for Mac OS X developers from Apple these days.

Comment: Don't know how it was in previous versions, but X Code 4 doesn't have iOS Library installed by default.