# No more quick help in Xcode editor

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

Quick help has gone away in my Xcode 5 (5.0.2 on OS X 10.8.5):

Instead of the little popup window that's supposed to pop up for the **`Opt` - Click** shortcut all that ever shows is the arrow image:

[image: Quick help popup missing]

Been like this since the Xcode 5 upgrade.
Any ideas how to fix it..?

**FWIW:** The doc sets are in fact properly installed - 'Opt' + Double-Click brings up the correct documentation as usual. Even removing the doc sets manually and re-downloadig didn't help.

The hovering *Quick Help* window is still gone..

Comment: Um... do you have documentation installed? If not, refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420257/xcode-how-to-install-the-ios-documentation-in-xcode

Comment: Does re-"Build" or restarting xCode helps. Sometimes xCode does that to me and that's how I solve it.

Comment: Tried all the magic - rebuild, deleting all known Xcode caches manually, have restarted the machine dozens of times since installing - it's been there from the start. Doc sets are of course installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick Help behaves this way if JavaScript is disabled, and certain configurations seem to cause Xcode to write a user default disabling JavaScript following the upgrade. To fix it, delete the user default by running the following command from Terminal, then relaunch Xcode.

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitJavaScriptEnabled
```

Comment: defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitJavaScriptEnabled  is not working for me.Getting the following error. Domain (com.apple.dt.Xcode) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.

Answer (score 7):

Close Xcode then delete `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`.

Reopen Xcode and option click on whatever you were interested in.

It seems to take a bit of time to be available after deleting the above directory.  I option clicked a couple of things and after the third click it started working. Be patient!

Working for me on Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer didn't work for me. The below code worked. Run the following command from Terminal, then relaunch Xcode.

`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable`

Comment: Thanks! Matts solution also did not work for me, but this did. Why would indexing have been disabled in the first place!?

Answer (score 1):

It started working (`Xcode 8.1`) after I did go to: `Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> Switch to Documentation (if you are on Simulators)`

Hit the download the documentation button.
I did need to restart Xcode and also hit the `Check and Install Now` button. Before this it was not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue yesterday. It happened after I disconnected my iPhone from my computer, the target device switched to "Generic iOS Devices". All of a sudden, quick help stopped working, the symbols lost their icons in the auto-completion pop-up.

I just tried select any of the simulator device to get it working again. Or you can just reconnect your iOS device.