# What is Xcode's 'Compiler Default' for C++ language settings?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5, clang, llvm

In the Xcode 5 (and probably 4) project settings -
How can we find out what '*Compiler Default*' actually resolves to for the **Apple LLVM - Language - C++** setting?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it's C++03. (Try writing some simple C++11 construct, does it work?)

Comment: `auto` does, range-based for does, lambdas don't. There you go.

Comment: Oh, that's... *interesting.* I'd recommend you set the language version explicitly anyway (`-std=c++98`, `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`).

Comment: Yes, did that for most projects. Thing is: I'm now getting linker errors (mismatching c++ std lib as far as I can tear the gibberish  apart) with other stuff compiled with *Compiler Default* .. sigh!

Comment: if the default C++ stdlib is not good enough for the compiler, then try adding `-stdlib=libc++` (and you may need to adjust your sysroot as well, but try this flag for now).

Comment: According to the Help Inspector, the compiler default is "GNU++98".

Comment: The compiler default for both is based on the toolchain you've selected in  Build Options. With Xcode 5, Apple LLVM 5.0 is what you get, which is clang++ using -std=c++11 and libc++ respectively. So my builds tell me, anyway. But the easiest way to tell is look a the build log verbosely. Mine with everything set defaults is `-std=c++11` and the related lib is nowhere to be found (I assume it is `libc++`).

Comment: Scratch that. @MartinR is totally right. I had C++11 selected in my dialect. my bad. +1 to you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the "Quick Help Inspector" in Xcode 5.0.2, the current "Compiler Default" is "GNU++98", which corresponds to the compiler option "-std=gnu++98".

It can also be seen in the compiler source code (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CompilerInvocation_8cpp_source.html, line 01057):

```
01033   if (LangStd == LangStandard::lang_unspecified) {
01034     // Based on the base language, pick one.
01035     switch (IK) {
01036     case IK_None:
01037     case IK_AST:
01038     case IK_LLVM_IR:
01039       llvm_unreachable("Invalid input kind!");
01040     case IK_OpenCL:
01041       LangStd = LangStandard::lang_opencl;
01042       break;
01043     case IK_CUDA:
01044       LangStd = LangStandard::lang_cuda;
01045       break;
01046     case IK_Asm:
01047     case IK_C:
01048     case IK_PreprocessedC:
01049     case IK_ObjC:
01050     case IK_PreprocessedObjC:
01051       LangStd = LangStandard::lang_gnu99;
01052       break;
01053     case IK_CXX:
01054     case IK_PreprocessedCXX:
01055     case IK_ObjCXX:
01056     case IK_PreprocessedObjCXX:
01057       LangStd = LangStandard::lang_gnucxx98;
01058       break;
01059     }
01060   }
```

Comment: Cheers! I must be blind - but Quick Help for the build options was amongst the first things I've tried, yet it's blank for all build settings. Then again, something appears to be wrong on my Xcode 5 installation... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945758/no-more-quick-help-in-xcode-editor)