# Xcode Quick Help displays "No Quick Help" when viewing a single file

Tags: xcode, code-documentation

The quick help feature is working just fine when I open an Xcode project, however when opening a file (e.g. `abc.swift`) that's not in an open project, the documentation does not appear.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Hopefully this will help you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945758/no-more-quick-help-in-xcode-editor

Comment: @AnkurJAIN thank you for sharing, I have checked that question before posting, Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: You're saying that you've opened a single file by itself, that's not contained in an open project?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Exactly!

Comment: Trying to bump this up, I also have the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688129/xcode-9-3-quick-help-optionclick-shows-empty

Answer (score 5):

Install the version of the `Command Line Tools` for your Xcode

```
`Xcode menu -> Open developer tools -> More Developer Tools
```

Restart Xcode. It helped me to see Quick Help again and also fixed git crash.

Answer (score 5):

The below code worked for me. Run the following command from Terminal, then relaunch Xcode.

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
```

Comment: If this is not working, try `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` .But this will clear all defaults .

Answer (score 1):

As an occasional user of XCode, what I still needed to do was download the documentation, which was not installed with the XCode install and/or did not carry over from a previous version of XCode.

From the Preferences dialog, click the Components tab, click on Documentation, and then click the download button for Guides and Sample Code.

Probably obvious for regular users of XCode, but I thought I would write it out for anyone else having this problem, since this was at the top of the Google search.

Comment: The only things showing in my Components tab are simulators

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I closed Xcode and then deleted `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`.
Then I reopened Xcode and checked. It worked after that. I'm currently on Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: I deleted that file and restarted xcode but it is in not responding state since long. Is this normal?

Comment: I don't think it's normal. Maybe you should re-install now.

Comment: Will think about it if issue persists

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me, just move the **Xcode.app** into **Applications** folder if not exist over here ;)