# Xcode 9.3 Quick Help (option+click) shows empty

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Any suggestions to make xcode9.3 quick help window show actual documentation, it currently shows empty after "I jump to the definition" (cmd+click) file. It is extremely annoying because this is how I navigate the documentation and find the property or function I am looking for by reading the quick help description

**Example:**

I option+click anything on my controller and the information shows.

[image]

Now, **after I follow the definition** to the file the property is declared in. The quick help **documentation ceases to work** FOR anything. `UIGestureRecognizer`, `Int`, or the properties. **This happens** to any properties/functions **to any built-in framework**! After I jump to the definition file.

[image]

**Latest NOTE**: June7th. 
Deleted both xcode8.3.2 and xcode9.3, restarted computer and reinstalled xcode (now 9.4) from app store this time. Quick help documentation still does not show up after I jump to definition file. smh + fml

Comment: Looks like Xcode bug. It happens, just try to restart it

Comment: I have restarted it many times. Including reinstalling it (not from the app store though, i have the .xip file I downloaded from the developers portal)

Comment: On a side note, I also have xcode8.3.2 available under Applications and the problem does not occur in that one, only in xcode9.3. Could having both be the problem?

Comment: Try to install the Xcode 9.3 in a different directory